# Bag of Words - Add feature manually

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to improve my model on text classification.

```
text = df['text']
count_vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1,ngram_range=(1, 2), 
stop_words="english", max_features=200)
count_vect.fit(text)
counts = count_vect.transform(text)
```

Here is the sample output:

```
[(u'spring', 386), (u'https', 341), (u'com', 317), (u'pr', 313), (u'for 
the', 285), (u'the pr', 208), (u'need', 196), (u'session', 164), 
(u'jp', 158), (u'png', 156), (u'updated', 154), (u'please', 152), 
(u'see', 145)]
```

I want to add word/frequencies manually which I thought could be a good indicator.
Any help on this?

Comment: Counts are frequencies.  Are you asking for help in adding the count values as a feature in your design matrix?  Or are you asking for some kind of transformation on the frequencies you have listed?  Also, by "word" do you mean the unigrams and bigrams you have listed in `counts`, or do you mean unigrams only?

Comment: Yes. I am asking help on adding the count values as a feature. I mean unigrams only.

Comment: Just add to the end of the text (say, call it `featured_text`) these unigrams in any order required times. you can create a special function. There is no meaning order for CountVectorizer, so, it is OK. May be it's not a best solution, but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
total = sum([x[1] for x in counts])
frequencies = [(x[0], x[1]/total) for x in counts]
```